# Disable checkboxes after selection is finished

Tags: vba, checkbox, disabled-input

I have a sheet, where one of the columns has 10 checkboxes in one where user can select multiple options.

Is there any way to keep this set of checks unchangeable after user has checked on needed options? Or any other way for user to select 1 or more options (not with list drop-downs)

My situation is like this:

For each row, the user has to select a range of checkboxes (labels of checkboxes tell about type of documents attached for that specific record) There is no further action, just check and save. Is there any macro, or any way to do this beside the actual way (with checkboxes)?

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub CheckBox1_Click()
  CheckBox1.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

I will explain you the complete process.

```
Add a checkbox Then
Make sure the Design Mode is Selected
Right Click on the CheckBox and click on View Code
And there place this code Make sure the CCheckbox name is according to your checkbox
```

Now whenever the user Checks the checkbox it will get disabled.

Comment: Thaks for answering. I don't kow why, but class Checkboxes is not recognized, error 1004 is generated

Comment: And one imp thing i forget to mention When you are inserting the checkbox there will be two types of controls ActiveX and Form. So add a checkbox from ActiveX Controls. Then only will this solution work

Comment: Thanks so much. I already had inserted ActiveX Checkbox. Everything worked fine. Thanks again.